# Display PHP data in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a basic family tree website that has each person as follows:

```
<a href="extract.php?id=John Dice" class="md-trigger" data-modal="modal-3" id ="Mohammed Ishaq Sharief">John Dice</a>
```

The `extract.php` is a basic php script that takes the `id` from the `href` tag and extracts that persons information from the database. Now the `php` script displays data in a plain manner (white backgroud and plain black text). If you look closely as at the '`href' tag it should display a modal which is coded as follows:

```
<div class="md-modal md-effect-1" id="modal-3">
    <div class="md-content">
        <h3>Person Information</h3>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><strong>Name:</strong> John Dice.</li>
                <li><strong>DOB:</strong> 28th July 1995.</li>
                <li><strong>BirthPlace:</strong> Chicago.</li>
                <li><strong>Occupation:</strong> Student.</li>
                <li><strong>About:</strong> Information.</li>
                <li><strong>Contact:</strong> Contact stuff.</li>
            </ul>
            <button class="md-close">Close </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For now I have the values hard coded , but I want the data I extract from the `php` to be displayed inside this modal on the same page. I've gone through a few question and know that a modal is loaded as soon as the page is loaded but it is hidden and the only way to pass any data into it through Ajax and Javascript which I have no clue about. Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Note: This is not an academic project nor will I be uploading this on a server.

Comment: so what actually is it?

Comment: self education and yes digitization of family records

Answer (score 0):

You can seperate the result by creating a page for the result

result.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Remote file for Bootstrap Modal</title>  
 </head>
 <body>
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
             <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
            <!-- /modal-header -->
        <div class="modal-body">

              <?php 
                  ///fetch from DB
                  $id = $_GET['id']; //to test it works with php GET

               ?>

          <!--put the result from DB here--->

          <ul>
             <li><strong>Name:</strong><?php echo $id;?> John Dice.</li>

              <!--put the result from DB here--->

              <ul>
                 <li><strong>Name:</strong> John Dice.</li>
                 <li><strong>DOB:</strong> 28th July 1995.</li>
                 <li><strong>BirthPlace:</strong> Chicago.</li>
                 <li><strong>Occupation:</strong> Student.</li>
                 <li><strong>About:</strong> Information.</li>
               <li><strong>Contact:</strong> Contact stuff.</li>
             </ul>

        </div>
           <!-- /modal-body -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
           <!-- /modal-footer -->
 </body>
</html>
```

And your Modal trigger

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
      <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>

     <a data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-info" href="result.php?id=123" data-target="#myModal">Click me !</a>

 <!-- Modal -->
     <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
       </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
   </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
 </div>
 <!-- /.modal -->
    </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question was broad that I do not know how to begin with. But
Firstly, You cannot run this if you will not upload on a server with a php apache and mysql running.

Second, if you do not know how to manipulate data from the server using php/mysql, I recommend you learn it from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp).

Third, if you want to learn ajax, and bootstrap, seems that is a searchable using [everybody's friend](http://www.google.com).

I recommend you to use jquery for the ajax part because you cannot use the bootstrap modal without jquery included so take an advantage to that one like,

```
$('your-button').on('click', function() { 
   //send your .post request here similar to ajax request
   $.post('request.php', { id: 'the value of id that was clicked', function(data) {
       $('.modal-body').html(data);
       $('your modal selector').modal();
   });
});
```

In your `request.php`, make a query for that filtering the passed `id` that was click and make an unordered list for the data which is you had wrote already.\

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Oh I have wamp server and I am using that for the php scripts. Just that i wont deploy it to a web server

Comment: I dont think you really understood my the question. You've given answers for all the stuff i already have. I just wanted to parse the `php` stuff into the modal. I am not manipulating the data from the database, its basic extraction and display. I was asking for a solution sans Ajax , if there is no way to do it with just php then ill go on Ajax

Answer (score 0):

Can try this ?

html :

```
<a class="ajax_modal" href="modal.php?data=ini datanya">Open Modal</a>
```

jQuery :

```
(function( $ ) {

  'use strict';

  $(document).on('click', '.modal-dismiss', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.magnificPopup.close();
  });

  $('.ajax_modal').magnificPopup({
    type: 'ajax',
    modal: true
  });
}).apply( this, [ jQuery ]);
```

modal.php

```
<?php
$data = $_GET["data"];
?>

<div id="custom-content" class="modal-block modal-block-md">
  <section class="panel">
    <header class="panel-heading bg-primary"><h2 class="panel-title" style="color: #ffffff;"><span class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Modal Header</h2></header>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          Data diterima : '<strong><?php print $data; ?></strong>'
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="panel-footer bg-default" style="padding: 10px;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
          <div class="col-xs-8" align="left"><strong>Modul information</strong></div>
          <div class="col-xs-4" align="right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary modal-dismiss"><strong>Close</strong></button></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </section>
</div>
```

Hope this help.